# Creating JSON array with information retrieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, json, web

I am trying to create a JSON array with the information selected from a database but I cannot give the array a name.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        $arr = array('isim' => $row['ename'], 'yer' => $row['eplace'], 'top' => $row['society'], 'tar' => $row['edate'], 'saat' => $row['ehour']);
        echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

I want to see the result;

> {"events":[{"isim":"eere","yer":"dddd","top":"asdfsdffgdfgdfg","tar":"2013-10-18","saat":"12:46"}{"isim":"fhjfr","yer":"yhjrhj","top":"ryjryjrj","tar":"2013-10-30","saat":"12:45"}{"isim":"sfsgsg","yer":"sfgssfg","top":"sgsfgsg","tar":"2013-10-31","saat":"12:45"}]}

But I cannot see the

> {"events":[

in the beggining and

> ]}

at the end.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To generate valid JSON, you first need to add everything to a multi-dimensional array and only then when that is complete, encode it:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        $arr[] = array('isim' => $row['ename'], 'yer' => $row['eplace'], 'top' => $row['society'], 'tar' => $row['edate'], 'saat' => $row['ehour']);
        // or perhaps just: $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Also note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

To put everything under an `events` key, you would need something like:

```
$arr['events'][] = array('isim' => $row['ename'], 'yer' => $row['eplace'], 'top' => $row['society'], 'tar' => $row['edate'], 'saat' => $row['ehour']);
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I add {"events":[ part. I think it is the name of the JSON node? Can I just write it in echo?

Comment: Still wondering when Oracle will implement an SQL JSON function within MySQL based on SELECT/INSERT and UPDATE querys (MySQL 5.5+ already makes use off JSON algorithm within EXPLAIN statement).. XML is already there within SQL function ExtractValue..